# reloading part of a tab and it's label counter, but staying there without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

may I ask for assistance regarding this piece of code? I'm reloading a part of a div (which is basically a tab with counter on it's label) to update the current number of items in it. I am able to successfully reload the part of the div only using:

`$("#custom-tabs-one-tab").load(location.href + " #custom-tabs-one-tab");`
.

This is the part of the code that I'm trying to reload. (this div only)

```
<div class="card-header p-0 pt-1" id="append_note_data_counter_tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="custom-tabs-one-tab" role="tablist">
        <?php if ($user['appendtimekeepingapproval'] == 'true') { ?>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#append_note-tab1" aria-controls="append_note-tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Append Timekeeping Approval&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-primary"><?php echo $eatimekeepingcountapproval; ?></span></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($user['authorizedovertimeapproval'] == 'true') { ?>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#append_note-tab2" aria-controls="append_note-tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Authorized Overtime Approval&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $eaovertimecountapproval; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($user['changescheduleapproval'] == 'true') { ?>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#append_note-tab3" aria-controls="append_note-tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Change Schedule Approval&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-warning"><?php echo $hrchangeschedcountapproval; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($user['departmentscheduleapproval'] == 'true') { ?>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#append_note-tab4" aria-controls="append_note-tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Department Schedule Approval&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-danger"><?php echo $easchedulelistcountapproval; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this method as well, but no luck.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#custom-tabs-one-tab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

The tab is reloading and is updating the counter, but the problem is that it's not staying in it's previous tab selection, it always goes back to the first one.

Is there a workaround for this concern? Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the active tab after the div is reloaded by passing a callback to the `.load` function. Something like this:

```
$("#custom-tabs-one-tab").load(location.href + " #custom-tabs-one-tab", function() {
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#custom-tabs-one-tab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I'm confused, I will study more on this, I did not know we can add function inside .load().